# Edge 12 JSON API response is transformed to UTF8 char

Tags: javascript, json, microsoft-edge

I got a strange issue occuring only on Edge 12 (Edge 13 is fine). When calling my JSON API, I get a 200 response, yet response body is composed of a single unicode character instead of an expected JSON array.

I am sending header:

```
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
```

Is there any known issue similar to mine with Edge12? :/